# Meaning of FB symbol in schematics?

Tags: schematics, symbol

What does "FB" mean? I can only guess it's some kind of protective device because of F, like with FU for fuse.

Is there any comprehensive online guide for such kind of symbols?

Comment: Can you provide an example schematic?

Comment: This symbol was on power source board. The device itself is small black ("metallic") cylinder without any visible signs on it. There were 3 of them.

Comment: Can you provide image?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your description, sounds like an abbreviation for [Ferrite Bead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead).

Comment: There is no other explanation. Its magnetic, resistance is minimal in both directions, appears among jumpers, color is right. And it is also protective device. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

FB is the designator for a ferrite bead.  A FB acts a lot like an inductor, in that it filters out AC, and they slow transition of DC signals.

Best list of [designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator) I've run across is in Wikipedia.