# What is the component on the schematic indicated by the symbol of a diagonal rectangle with a line through it?

Tags: components, schematics, ferrite-bead

I can't for the life of me, figure out what these diagonal rectangles are...

[image: a busy cat]

Help?

Comment: FB = Ferrite beads?

Comment: yeah, Ferrite Bead with 2A ratings.

Comment: Are you referring to `FB10` & `FB12` or to `J6` which is probably some sort of edge connector. Where did you find the image?

Comment: @jippie J6 is almost certainly a typical pin and barrel power connector, with an optional switched contact on the barrel that has been shorted and ignored in this application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of FB symbol in schematics?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75607/meaning-of-fb-symbol-in-schematics)

Comment: Usually Altera FPGA reference schematics use this notation for ferrite beads.

Answer (score 16):

Those are [ferrite beads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead), rated at 50 \$\text{m}\Omega\$ DC resistance and 2A. At low frequencies, they are predominantly inductive, but become more resistive (lossy) at high frequencies. They are very useful tools for electromagnetic compatibility. They come in surface mount packages, like what is most likely intended for that schematic, as well as clamp-ons for cables.

Comment: Rated for 2A and with a resistance of 0.05 ohm.

Comment: That's 0.05Ω at DC (0Hz).

Comment: The symbol is probably supposed to look like the edge view of a toroidal ferrite core with a wire threaded through it.