# What is this symbol that looks like a parallelogram?

Tags: arm, soc

[image: parallelogram electronics symbol]
it says "180ohm at 100MHz" next to it. So I'm guessing that it's a non-air-core inductor. It seems to fit this: [What is this symbol on the schematic?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143891/what-is-this-symbol-on-the-schematic) - except that the symbol is slightly different than what's in that answer. Wanted to confirm.

this is part of Atmel at91sam3d (ARM SoC) schematic.

Comment: It's a representation of a ferrite bead.  This is a tiny toroid made from one of several ferrite materials that is simply slipped over a wire (usually bare wire) and is free to move around somewhat.  It's used to reduce or suppress high-frequency signals.

Comment: @user2943160 It's not because this question is the other way around. He doesn't know what the component is.

Comment: The symbol in the duplicate is not the same as the OP.

Comment: @laptop2d the accepted answer covers a variety of symbols for ferrite beads, including the symbol in this question.

Comment: @user2943160 yeah, the question should have not been marked as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means a **ferrite bead**.

They are used for noise suppression and are specified usually in terms of impedance at a certain frequency - the higher the impedance, the more it will block those frequencies.