# I need help on identifying the value of a schematic symbol

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, datasheet, lora, component-values

[image]

I came across the schematic of RAK3272-Sip development board, but I couldn't identify the value of this inductor.

[Here's a link that contains the full schematic.](https://docs.rakwireless.com/Product-Categories/WisDuo/RAK3272-SiP-Breakout-Board/Datasheet/#hardware)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This symbol is used to represent a ferrite bead (see [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143891/what-is-this-symbol-on-the-schematic)), a device typically used as a filter on power supply lines.

In this case `120` will specify the impedance of the bead in Ohms at some frequency. Typically it would be measured at 100MHz, so you would be searching for a ferrite bead specified as 120R @ 100MHz.

Of course without a BoM (bill of materials) we can't know the exact specifications of the ferrite bead used. Two different parts with the same single point value can have wildly different impedance vs frequency responses.

---

The answers in the linked question appear to suggest the value would be peak of the impedance, however that seems atypical - I tend to come across them valued using the @100MHz specification.

Comment: Sometimes you'll see ferrite beads spec'd at a different frequency, but it's usually unrelated to where the peak impedance is. I've seen some spec'd at 1 MHz before, for instance.

Comment: If you need to replace it, the value usually isn't a critical parameter.